# Reverse ToStringBuilder : convert string to object

Tags: java

Is there a way to convert my output from [ToStringBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) back to java object?

I am looking for an easy way to represent a Java object in readable text file and being able to convert back and forth between string and object.

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot use the `Serializable` interface?

Comment: by output of ToStringBuilder what do you mean, can you post the code.

Comment: @dacwe - he said "readable" ;)

Comment: I can produce a string from java object using ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(Object object)

Comment: perhaps it's worth mentioning this is the ToStringBuilder from apache commons ;)

Answer (score 2):

You must define a strict format and follow it with a parser. There are two accepted formats:

- XML - you can use [`java.beans.XMLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html)
- JSON - use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

If you don't choose these formats you will have to handle the parsing yourself.

The `ToStringBuilder` does not seem to have a reverse equivalent. Furthermore it is wrong to use this string representation for such purposes - it is meant only for debug.

Comment: I don't want to introduce new library into my app. XMLEncoder looks like a good one but i don't know it will work bc my app is using a very old version of axis.

Comment: the version of axis has nothing to do with any of my suggestions. Adding a library should be trivial.

Comment: why it is wrong? protocol buffer from google has something similar and it doesn't use xml.

Comment: Well, yes, protobuf is another option. I didn't say it's wrong to use some string format. I said it's wrong to use the one generated by any form of `toString()`. It is only for debug. (JSON is similar to the protobuf text format)

Comment: actually you can parse your protobuf object from its toString() output. That is actually give me an idea to do something similar with ToStringBuilder bc i am using that to generate logging information.

Comment: @Sean, XMLEncoder is built in. It isn't an additional library.  I would add XStream to the list as I found it is very easy to work with and customise for XML and JSon.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to parse your string representation of the object and then construct a new object initialised with those values.

If you want to keep it generic and have it work for any  object type, you can use [Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils) to help.

For example, if your string representation is:

```
Person@7f54[name=Stephen,age=29,smoker=false]
```

Parse out the class name, fields and values. Then use BeanUtils to construct a new `Person`:

```
String className = "Person";
Class beanClass = Class.forName(className);
Person myPerson = (Person)beanClass.newInstance();
BeanUtils.setProperty(myPerson, "name", "Stephen");
BeanUtils.setProperty(myPerson, "age", "29");
BeanUtils.setProperty(myPerson, "smoker", "false");
```

This assumes that your `Person` class is a bean and exposes getters/setters for its fields.

Comment: i really don't want to write a parser also it get complicate really quick when the property of your bean is another object.

Answer (score 1):

Sean, I came across your question while looking for a simple test case converter based on a reflection-based String output of an object.  While a more robust library for json or XML is certainly important for a wide range of input, this is handy for quick and dirty test cases.  It handles simple, non-nested POJOs.  Its only dependency is apache commons.

I'm using this toString format:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
}
```

Here is the class:

```
public class FromStringBuilder {

/**
 * Parses a string formatted with toStringBuilder
 * 
 * @param input - ex. "Path[id=1039916,displayName=School Home,description=<null>,...]"
 * @return hashmap of name value pairs - ex. id=1039916,... 
 */
public static Map<String, String> stringToMap(String input) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> ret = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    String partsString = StringUtils.substringBetween(input, "[", "]");
    String[] parts = partsString.split(",");
    for (String part:parts) {
        String[] nv = part.split("=");
        if (!StringUtils.equals("<null>", nv[1])) {
            ret.put(nv[0], nv[1]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public static <T> T stringToObject(String input, Class<T> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    Map<String, String> map = stringToMap(input);
    T ret = clazz.newInstance();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(ret, map);
    return ret;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) library is the perfect one

Comment: I really don't want to use XML bc my application is still using very old version of axis. Library conflict in here.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example of using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):**

```
public class GsonTest {
    static class Name { String first; String last; }
    static class Data { int number; Name name = new Name(); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Data data1 = new Data();
        data1.number = 1;
        data1.name.first = "Joe";
        data1.name.last = "Smith";
        print("data1", data1);

        String jsonString = gson.toJson(data1);
        System.out.println("jsonString: " + jsonString);

        Data data2 = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Data.class);
        print("data2", data2);
    }

    private static void print(String id, Data data) {
        System.out.println(id + "     :" 
                + " number=" + data.number 
                + " name.first=" + data.name.first
                + " name.last=" + data.name.last);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
data1     : number=1 name.first=Joe name.last=Smith
jsonString: {"number":1,"name":{"first":"Joe","last":"Smith"}}
data2     : number=1 name.first=Joe name.last=Smith
```

**Speed**

Gson should be roughly as fast as any other comparable *reflection-based* Object<->Text serialization framework, but I do not have benchmark data.

**Bean Support**

Unlike XStream(optionally) and java.beans.XMLEncoder/XMLEncoder, Gson does not use a class's setter and getter methods.  Rather it reads and writes the member fields of the class directly, similar to Java binary serialization (ObjectOutputStream, etc.)  While Gson should be able to properly marshal and unmarshal most JavaBeans, this implementation detail of Gson must be kept in mind and accounted for.

**Pretty-printed JSON Output**

By default GSON outputs JSON all on one line, as an optimization.  It can output JSON that is slightly easier to read.  Do this by constructing the Gson object in a slightly different way:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

The JSON output (continuing the example above), now looks like:

```
{
  "number": 1,
  "name": {
    "first": "Joe",
    "last": "Smith"
  }
}
```

instead of

```
{"number":1,"name":{"first":"Joe","last":"Smith"}}
```

Comment: Do you know how fast is Gson and can you post the output?

Comment: @Sean - I posted the output.  I do not have benchmark data for Gson.  Gson _should_ be about as fast as other similar frameworks.

Comment: Do you mean that Gson will change the visibility of my private field?

Comment: @Sean - Gson doesn't change your code.  But when it converts an object to a string, all the fields of the object, and objects within objects, will show up in the JSON string, even private fields.  The only fields that Gson excludes by default are [`transient` fields](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient).  This behavior can be customized, but this is more advanced usage of Gson, described in its documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to format json output. It prints everything in the same line and my output is very large, it is not readable if it is in 1 line.

Comment: @Sean - Yes.  I updated the main answer with more info.  The short answer is, construct Gson with ---- `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();`.