# Parse to JSON a serializable java object in log file logstash

Tags: logstash, grok

I'm parsing some log files with grok, but I have the following trace:

```
[es.org.some.Object[
 attr1=-54612
 attr2=2015-01-28
 attr3=4030
 searchTags=[love, peace, rock]
 ]]
```

This trace is a serialized java object.

My objetive is to parse this string to JSON, like this:

```
{
"es.org.some.Object": {
    "attr1": "-54612",
    "attr2": "2015-01-28",
    "attr3": "4030",
    "searchTags": [
        "love",
        "peace",
        "rock"
    ]
}
}
```

How can I achive this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here are few ideas how to parse the string representation and instantiate an object: [Reverse ToStringBuilder : convert string to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343860/reverse-tostringbuilder-convert-string-to-object)

Then it's just a matter of choice of jSon serializing library to have the object serialized back to a jSon string.